# angular insert component tag into innerHTML and resolve components after

Tags: angular

I have a html containing component tags which i want to load it in a DOM elements innerHTML and resolve components after that, but angular doesnt recognize its as component tags after appending it into DOM innerHTML

```
export class FormViewComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('myElement') myElement: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('myTestComponent') myTestComponent: MyTestComponent;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.myElement.nativeElement.innerHTML= '<app-test-component #myTestComponent></app-test-component>';
        this.myTestComponent.data = {name: 'myName'};
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the way you should be rendering dynamic components https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: in this guide it is needed to load <ng-template ad-host></ng-template> tag at the first app load but in my app i do not have any tag in this time and i add it manual after component template loaded @Andrei